# Promise in Firebase for google actions

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How do I run this asynchronous task of reading data from firebase?
I Get say="before" but i want say="after".

```
app.intent("Default Welcome Intent - yes",(conv)=>{

  var db=admin.database(firebaseApp);
  var ref= db.ref("xyz/1");
  var movie;
  var say="before";
  ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
    movie=snapshot.val();

    say="after";
  });
  console.log("say is"+say);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Promise in your Intent Handler, then you **must** also return that Promise so the app dispatcher knows that there is an asynchronous operation going on.

You have a second issue that you're trying to execute code (the `console.log()`) outside of the Promise resolution (the `.then()` portion), but expecting a value from inside that resolution. That portion if the code may execute before the portion inside the `then()` does. If you want code to be executed after the Promise resolves, you *must* include it inside the `then()` portion.

So your code might look something like

```
app.intent("Default Welcome Intent - yes",(conv)=>{

  var db=admin.database(firebaseApp);
  var ref= db.ref("xyz/1");
  var movie;
  var say="before";
  return ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
    movie=snapshot.val();

    say="after";
    console.log("say is"+say);
  });
});
```